# Make image popup in content article automatically

Tags: joomla, popup, article

i want to make a content plugin in Joomla, in which whenever i insert image it automatically converts into popup.

for this i will use Jcemediapopup, it uses class="jcemediapopup"

i now just simply wants, whenever user insert image in article, with the help of our plugin that `<img src`  line coverts into like this `<img class="jcemediapopup" src=`

so that all image become Popup.

Any help !

Comment: can you show your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless you want to write a plugin for this, you can do it in a template override, eg. to apply this to e content article:

- copy /components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php to
  /templates/yourtemplate/html/com_content/article/default.php
- where the article content is echoed (around line 187), apply the following:

change

```
<?php echo $this->item->text; ?>
```

to something like

```
<?php echo preg_replace('/<img src="([^"]+)" ([^>]*)>/',
'<a href="\1"><img src="\1" class="jcemediapopup" \2></a>',$this->item->text); ?>
```

You might have to tweak the regexp if the images already contain a class-tag ...

Comment: Yes, it seems to work, but how can i make preg_replace to add class to <a> tag also...like you did for img tag.

Comment: Yes, now its opening in Popup, but Article itself is opening in Popup, instead of Image on which i click. when i hardcoded image name then its opening fine. Can you please tell me how can give href of image dynamically.

Comment: Hi, updated the regex. It's OK to try to modify the regex for yourself, even if it looks a little greek to you. I'll try to explain it: You read the regex from left to right. The current regex looks for an img-tag with a src-attribute. It matches any character inside the "-s of the src-attribute except for another ". The value of the src is 'captured' by using (). Things that are captured can later be referenced by using the \1 (for the first capture), \2 for the second capture etc. The replace-part of the function should then be pretty self explanatory. regards

Comment: Thank you very much, now its working perfect...
you are really great with regex, that's true Regex looks Greek to me. Will try to understand this code
Thanks Anyways

One more question, is this also work with K2 Items, or only Joomla Articles?

Comment: Hi, it should work with k2 also, try it out. There will be a problem if img-tags in the k2-object already contains a class-attribute, if ' is used instead of " in the img-tag, or if the alt-attribute is shown before the src-attribute in the img-tag (unlikely). Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i could not vote up your answer, bcz of less reputation otherwise Many Thanks.
anyways i converted this code to joomla plugin and yes it is working with k2 also.